# Why this Angular code don't work?

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

Now, i'm trying to understand how Angular.js working with "Angular.js in 60 Minutes" by Dan Wahlin. And i stuck with this code, which in browser must look like this: http://oi59.tinypic.com/25im4cy.jpg

My code:

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" ng-app="demoApp">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Angular.js</title>
</head>
<body>

    <div>
        <div ng-view></div>
    </div>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="angular.min.js"></script>

    <script>
        var demoApp=angular.module('demoApp',[]);

        demoApp.config(function ($routeProvider) {
            $routeProvider
                .when('/',
                {
                    controller: 'SimpleController',
                    templateUrl: 'View1.html'   
                })
                .when('/view2',
                {
                    controller: 'SimpleController',
                    templateUrl: 'View2.html'
                })
                .otherwise({redirectTo:'/'});
        });

        demoApp.controller('SimpleController', function ($scope){
            $scope.customers=[
                {name:'Sam',city:'Moscow'},
                {name:'Dan',city:'Dubna'},
                {name:'Alex',city:'Dmitrov'}
            ];

            $scope.addCustomer= function(){ 
                $scope.customers.push(
                    {
                        name: $scope.newCustomer.name, 
                        city: $scope.newCustomer.city
                    });
            };  
        });
    </script>


</body>
</html>
```

View1.html

```
<div class="container">
    <h2>View 1</h2>
    Name
    <br/>
    <input type="text" data-ng-model="filter.name"/>
    <br/>
    <ul>
        <li ng-repeat="cust in customers | filter:filter.name | orderBy:'name">{{cust.name | uppercase}} - {{cust.city | lowercase}}</li>
    </ul>

    <br/>
    Customer name: <br/>    
    <input type="text" ng-model="newCustomer.name">
    <br/>
    Customer city: <br/>
    <input type="text" ng-model="newCustomer.city">
    <br/>
    <button ng-click="addCustomer()">Add Customer</button>
    <br/>
    <a href="#/view2">View 2</a>
</div>
```

View2.html

```
<div class="container">
    <h2>View 2</h2>
    City
    <br/>
    <input type="text" data-ng-model="city"/>
    <br/>
    <ul>
        <li ng-repeat="cust in customers | filter:city | orderBy:'name">{{cust.name | uppercase}} - {{cust.city | lowercase}}</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

But, when i launch index.html in browser, there is nothing at all. Can somebody explain me what's the matter or, if you have already read this book, give me your version of code?

Comment: You forgot to include `ngRoute` module.

Answer (score 1):

This is because you have *not* done two things:

- Include the `ngRoute` module as a dependency when you declare `angular.module('demoApp', [])`
- Include `angular-route.js` script code in your project.

I created [this JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/467px16e/) from your code to show it working, just with the `View1` template, where all I have done is include `ngRoute` as a library and a dependency of the `demoApp` module.

In the future, you should check your development console, because Angular printed out an error.

Comment: Exactly. Check your dev console. Angular is GREAT about errors. It actually provided you a link in your console that told you the exact problem (i.e. ngRoute is now a separate module - since the book was written, I assume).

Comment: Thank you very much! Now, it's working great, but i have one more question: why there is no list of names and cities like in example? And how i can enable it?

Comment: @SergeyPavlov : There was a Unterminated quote in the expression. Add a qoute like **orderBy : 'name'**. Here is the updated [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/467px16e/2/).

Comment: Once again that was expressed in the console error output by Angular. Please, check your console!

Answer (score 0):

```
<body ng-app='demoApp'>
    <div>
        <div ng-view></div>
    </div>
</body>

<script type="text/ng-template" id="View1.html">
<div class="container">
    Name
    <input type="text" data-ng-model="filter.name"/>
    <ul>
        <li ng-repeat="cust in customers | filter:filter.name | orderBy:'name">{{cust.name | uppercase}} - {{cust.city | lowercase}}</li>
    </ul>

    <br/>
    Customer name: <br/>    
    <input type="text" ng-model="newCustomer.name">
    <br/>
    Customer city: <br/>
    <input type="text" ng-model="newCustomer.city">
    <br/>
    <button ng-click="addCustomer()">Add Customer</button>
    <br/>
    <a href="#/view2">View 2</a>
</div>

<script>
var demoApp=angular.module('demoApp',['ngRoute']);

        demoApp.config(function ($routeProvider) {
            $routeProvider
                .when('/',
                {
                    controller: 'SimpleController',
                    templateUrl: 'View1.html'   
                })
                .when('/view2',
                {
                    controller: 'SimpleController',
                    templateUrl: 'View2.html'
                })
                .otherwise({redirectTo:'/'});
        });

        demoApp.controller('SimpleController', function ($scope){
            $scope.customers=[
                {name:'Sam',city:'Moscow'},
                {name:'Dan',city:'Dubna'},
                {name:'Alex',city:'Dmitrov'}
            ];

            $scope.addCustomer= function(){ 
                $scope.customers.push(
                    {
                        name: $scope.newCustomer.name, 
                        city: $scope.newCustomer.city
                    });
            };  
        });
</script>
```